# Class library naming conventions

Tags: c#, naming

Typically in a C# program, the entry point is in Program.cs. However, if you  are creating a rather generic class library, with no Main() method, such as

`TCPClient.dll`

what is the appropriate base class name? (cannot be TCPClient as that is the namespace).

Comment: Class libraries have no main entry point so there is no need for a "base class."

Comment: If I have created a generic TCPClient class, for example, that I want to use in multiple projects, how do I avoid creating `TCPClient.dll` with a base class `TCPClient` (which I cannot) ? Which is wrong - my DLL name or my class name?

Comment: you can change the namespace to yourcompany or something

Comment: `YourCompany.Tcp.TcpClient` problem solved

Comment: The point of make a Class libraries is to have a easy way to share functionality, to distinct a class with the same name to another, use different namespaces. this is a good reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**There isn't one.**

The entrypoint is for your executable. There is *one*.

Your library has as much business declaring an entrypoint as do all the other files in your program, be they dynamically or statically linked; i.e. *none*.

Name the classes it declares however you like.